# Does prototypical inheritance in JavaScript demonstrate type polymorphism?

Tags: javascript, oop, polymorphism

Could it be said that prototypical inheritance in JavaScript demonstrates type polymorphism?

Or does the weak typing of JavaScript preclude that?

```
function Parent () {}

function Child () {}
Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;

// Is Child a polymorphic implementation of Parent?
```

Comment: in javascript, you can change any property at any time to any type.

Comment: Does that preclude type polymorphism? In some sense `Child` is-a `Parent` in my example.

Comment: it's been a while since i was in the classroom, but it sounds more like basic sub-typing to me...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Javascript uses constructors and prototyping to bring in it what it misses because it lacks classes.

You can do much with JavaScript even without understanding constructors and prototypes, but these are vital for a good handle over this powerful language.

Using constructors and prototypes allows Javascript to bring similar order to its objects as the one brought by classes to other languages. But not every type of usage of prototype is equivalent to inheritance and polymorphism.